# Do ultrasound mosquito-repellents work?

Tags: air, insect, ultrasonic, repellent, mosquitoes

There are many anti-mosquito devices for sell that use ultra sounds as a repellent (e.g. see [here](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=ultrasound%20mosquito%20repellent)).

Is it supported by science?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Female mosquitoes (males do not bite) are not known to be repelled by any sounds.

In particular, commercial ‘mosquito repellents’ based on ultrasounds (i.e., above human hearing range, >20 kHz) have been shown to be ineffective in females of a number of species including genus of *Anopheles*, *Aedes*, *Haemagogus* and *Verrallina* ([Schreck et al., 1984](https://doi.org/10.1080/10934528409375178); [Foster and Lutes, 1985](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/2906666/); [Jensen et al., 2000](https://doi.org/10.2987/8756-971X(2006)22%5B158:FEONMS%5D2.0.CO;2))

[Schreck et al. (1984)](https://doi.org/10.1080/10934528409375178)'s abstract also adds that:

> one of the [tested ultrasonic] devices gave off sound radiation which could be potentially harmful.